# Search External List Web Part

Tags: 2010, search, search-results, content-search-web-part, external-list

I have a SharePoint 2010 on-prem site with 2 external lists and I want to add web parts of those lists on a landing page with search boxes for each list that displays the results in the web part.

How do I get started with this? I know what I want to achieve and what it should look like, I'm not sure how to accomplish it. Do I build some sort of search tool first and put that on the page or do I build the web part and add the search tool to it?

Answer (score 1):

**You have the following options to search In External List.**

1. Create a `Content Source` to get data from `External Content Type`.
2. Create a `custom Search Scope` with `Search Core Result Web Part` to get data from a specific list
3. Create a custom search form via Jquery.

---

**(1) Create Content Source to get data from External Content Type**

- Go to Central Administration > Application Management > Manage service applications > Search Service Application > Crawling > Content Sources.
- Click on "New Content Source".
- select "Line of Business data" option in the Content Source Type section.

[image]

- select "Business Data Connectivity Service" > "Crawl selected external data source" > Click on Ok.
- Go to Central Administration > Application Management > Manage service applications > Search Service Application > Queries and Results > Scopes.
- Now Next, create a new page. Add the following 3 webparts:

  - Search Box
  - Search Core Results
  - Search Paging
- In search core result add ur scope.

For more details check [Search Scopes within BCS Data](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/c052a46a-fad7-4205-8f66-503ed46c072d/search-scopes-within-bcs-data-searching-a-specific-ectexternal-list?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

---

**(2) Create a custom Search Scope for your List.**

Instead of creating a content source for external content type, you can create directly custom scope for your list.

[image]

Check the detail steps at [Create a Search Scope for a Sharepoint 2010 List or Library](http://www.bentedder.com/create-a-search-scope-for-a-sharepoint-2010-list-or-library/)

---

**(3) Create a custom search form via Jquery**

Try to create a custom search form via Jquery as the following:

[image]

Check the detail steps at :

- [External List with BCS & Search Filters](https://arsalkhatri.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/external-list-with-bcs-search-filters-finders/)
- [Create a jQuery + SharePoint instant search/filter](http://www.bentedder.com/create-a-jquery-sharepoint-instant-searchfilter/)

Answer (score 1):

For External Content Type in CA you should create Profile Page.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/how-to-search-the-data-from-the-associated-external-content-type-in-sharepoint-2010/

After it the property Default Action must be initialized (in my case: http://portal:80/sites/dev/_bdc/http___portal_sites_dev/bcsCities_1.aspx?ID={0})

Add new Content Source as it's described by M.Qassas and perform Full Crawl for it. If everything is ok, in search center the query for "bcsCities_1.aspx" should return a result.

Add a Search Box into a page. Define value for web-part property "Additional query terms", in my case it was: Path:"bcsCities_1.aspx".

And Dropdown mode: Don not show scopes dropdown, and default to target results page, or Show scopes dropdown. In any case the context must be "All Sites".

The results of a search query will be displayed on page OSSSearchResults.aspx (or custom). There are no ability in SP2010 show results on the same page.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg576963(v=office.14).aspx